# Angular UI Bootstrap Navbar collapse and toggle issue

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Angular. I am struggling to have Bootstrap navbar working properly    in Angular UI.

```
Here is my jsfiddle example:    http://jsfiddle.net/serselt/oa8fhbL4/.
```

I would like to have the navbar-toggle (hamburger icon) always visible and clickable no matter what the size of the screen is. In addition I would like to show the contents of the navbar-collapse sidebar ("Option 1" and "Option 2" in my example) ONLY visible when the navbar-toggle icon is clicked on.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you please make the link work? For those of us on mobile it's not easy to look at.

Comment: My ex-colleague recommended to add a bunch of CSS changes to make it work. I updated the jsfiddle example so others could benefit from it : [URL](http://jsfiddle.net/serselt/oa8fhbL4/2/). Sorry @tuckerjt07 I am not clear how to do what you are asking, I am new to stackoverflow as well. Thanks.

Comment: Your comment did it this time. :) the original post the link isn't clickable on mobile.